# Is it possible to configure GNOME settings on Ubuntu through dconf database? Or is it possible to have a custom login (greeter) screen on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, login-screen, dconf

I have a custom login screen with a welcome screen on my CentOS machine, and I am trying to figure out how to do this on my Ubuntu as well.

My `/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-login-screen` looks like this:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
banner-message-enable = true
banner-message-text = 'Welcome'
disable-restart-buttons = true
disable-user-list = true
```

When I change this file and do `sudo dconf update` on my CentOS machine it reflects correctly to my GNOME login screen, custom welcome message, no user list, and my logo I want as well, however this same method does not work on my Ubuntu machine. I still get the same Ubuntu login screen as before.

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 @David